# "LVM failed to initialize library context" - SLES 12.3 after reboot lost some of its PVs

Tags: sles

After a reboot, a SLES 12.3 box doesn't recognizes a few disks (that are actually behind HW raid).

**What could the issue be?**

If I "head /dev/sdb | strings | head" the problematic disks, I can see data on them, ok.

But "pvscan" doesn't recognizes it.

```
SERVER:~ # pvck /dev/sdb
  Device /dev/sdb not found (or ignored by filtering).
SERVER:~ # 
SERVER:~ # grep '  filter' /etc/lvm/lvm.conf
    filter = [ "r|/dev/.*/by-path/.*|", "r|/dev/.*/by-id/.*|", "r|/dev/fd.*|", "r|/dev/cdrom|",  "a|/dev/sd.*[1-9]|", "a|/dev/vda[1-9]|", "a|/dev/mapper/.*|", "a|/dev/dm-*|" , "r|.*|" ]
SERVER:~ #
```

Strangely, the OS recognizes sda, which holds the OS itself.

But it doesn't recognizes the sdb/sdc/etc (holding the data) as PV.

**UPDATE** on 2018 Dec 11: all the disks: sda (raid1), sdb(raid5), sdc(raid5), sdd(raid1) are on HW RAID. "zypper up" says nothing to update.

Comment: There is a know bug after upgrades, especially when using multipath.

Comment: hmm, no multipath is used here, only HW RAID1 (which is sda) and HW RAID5, which is RAID5. But many thanks for any hint.

Comment: Any link/workaround to that bug? Many thanks.

Comment: Yes, but probably does not apply. https://www.suse.com/support/kb/doc/?id=7022520

Comment: sda is from HW RAID too and that works, but checking, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

finally, we found out:

It looks like something deleted the non-sda partitions :)

So the data was there on the ex.: sdb, sdc, sdd, but we had to re-run the partition creating oneliner:

```
parted -s /dev/sdb mklabel gpt mkpart primary xfs 0% 100% set 1 lvm on
```

and presto, pvscan found them! yay.